# How to stop tput bel from flashing the screen at internals

Tags: linux, macos, tput

I accidentally called `tput bel` on my Mac with iterm2 and now my terminal screen flashes at some interval. How to reverse the `tput bel` command?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: close the terminal and start another one?